# I want to blur only the image but it affects everything

Tags: html, css, border

I wanted to creat a `background image` `blur` I applied it and everything just blurred so here is the html and this is just fast re creation of the full project and if you didn't understand the `class names` talk to me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>HTML</title>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="trbp"><button class="trb">sign up</button></div>
 <div class="aio">
<h2 class="btp">welcom to</h2>
<h2 class="bth">our site</h2>
<button class="blb">about us</button></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css to help

```
    font-size: 15pt;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url("bto.jpg");
    filter: blur(8px)
}
.trbp{
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black;
}
.trb{
  position: relative;
  left: 440px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btp{
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 30px;
}
.bth{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}
.blb{
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 60px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0731D2;
}
```

Comment: What are you considering the image? Is there a class for the image? The CSS name is missing for the `background-image` Could you provide a markup photo or a relative reference so we can see the image?

Comment: Please check the code you have given, the CSS is missing at least the first line, maybe more, and make it into a working snippet that we can try out ourselves.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to understand and fix my scuffed code and I cannot believe that there's some people trying to help the begginers in there journey thank you but I tried the too answers and they worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code given in the question, and assuming it's the body that the background is required on, you can add a pseudo before element to the body and put the background on that and blur it.

That way only the image gets blurred, not everything else.

```css
body {
  font-size: 15pt;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

body::before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768");
  filter: blur(8px);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}

.trbp {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black;
}

.trb {
  position: relative;
  left: 440px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btp {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 30px;
}

.bth {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}

.blb {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 60px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0731D2;
}
```

```html
<div class="trbp"><button class="trb">sign up</button></div>
<div class="aio">
  <h2 class="btp">welcom to</h2>
  <h2 class="bth">our site</h2>
  <button class="blb">about us</button></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can apply it to a full size container as below, set the container size and position to absolute and then the rest of the content to relative and set the z-indexes.

```css
body, html{
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
position: relative;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.bgImageContainer{
  background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/people'); 
  width:100%; height:100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);z-index:0;
  position:absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index:-10;
 }
 
.trbp{
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black;
}
.trb{
  position: relative;
  left: 440px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btp{
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 30px;
}
.bth{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}
.blb{
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 60px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0731D2;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgImageContainer">
</div>

<div class="trbp"><button class="trb">sign up</button></div>
 <div class="aio">
<h2 class="btp">welcom to</h2>
<h2 class="bth">our site</h2>
<button class="blb">about us</button></div>
```

You can't directly use blur filter in body. But you could apply the background image and filter to a pseudo element on the body. You can use below code to add blur effect in your background.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_GUUtZTKhhfKuCm9q5Ab77HQ8KiTFng3usA0MdgVmIXBC5tgHk3XiecscRsddpRi4SA&usqp=CAU);
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    z-index: -1000; /* Keep the background behind the all your content */  height: 20%; width: 20%; 

    /* don't forget to use the prefixes you need */
    transform: scale(5);
    transform-origin: top left;
    filter: blur(1px);
}


.trbp{
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  border: black;
}
.trb{
  position: relative;
  left: 440px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btp{
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 30px;
}
.bth{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}
.blb{
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 60px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0731D2;
}
```

```html
<div class="trbp"><button class="trb">sign up</button></div>
 <div class="aio">
<h2 class="btp">welcom to</h2>
<h2 class="bth">our site</h2>
<button class="blb">about us</button></div>
```